# Is there an easy way to rebuild all ports?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

In the upgrade process for 10.1-RELEASE, I'm prompted with this:

```
Installing updates...
Completing this upgrade requires removing old shared object files.
Please rebuild all installed 3rd party software (e.g., programs
installed from the ports tree) and then run "/usr/sbin/freebsd-update install"
again to finish installing updates.
```

Is there a way to quickly rebuild all of my ports? Perhaps buried in portmaster's huge man page? I couldn't find it myself…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html, section 24.2.3.3:

`portmaster -af`

Forget about "quickly" though. This may take some time depending on your machine and the ports installed. :)

After that, you'll have to run `freebsd-update install` one last time.

Comment: Aha. portmaster really *can* do everything. Thanks.

Comment: `pkg-static upgrade -f` to reinstall using binary packages. `man pkg-upgrade` has the details. Not sure what happens if you hand-built some ports using custom build options.

Comment: pkg-static upgrade -f 
Worked for me. Thanks.